# How to setup eventListener for a LWC component to receive messages from an embedded iFrame

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, iframe

I am having trouble setting up an eventListener for my LWC component to listen messages received from an embedded iFrame.

I have a parent component where I have set the event listener in connectedCallback hook as follows:

```
export default class MainComponent extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
@track iFrameClassName = 'hideIFrame';

connectedCallback(){
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
        console.log("Message received from origin: " + event.origin);
        if(event.origin === "https://my.domain.com"){
            // Close iframe
            this.iFrameClassName = 'hideIFrame';
            console.log('CLASSNAME: ' + this.iFrameClassName);
        }
    });
}

openIFrameHandler(event){
    var parameters = event.detail;
    this.template.querySelector('c-child-component')
        .formIFrameUrl(parameters);
    this.iFrameClassName = 'showIFrame';
}
```

Parent component markup:

```
<template>
<lightning-layout horizontal-align="center">
    <c-child-component i-frame-class-name={iFrameClassName}></c-child-component>
</lightning-layout>
<c-product-table recordid={recordId} onopeniframe={openIFrameHandler}></c-product-table></template>
```

Child component js:

```
export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement {
  @track url;
  @api iFrameClassName
  @api
  formIFrameUrl(someparameters)
     this.url = 'www.my.domain.com/' + someparameters;
  }
```

Child component markup:

```
<template>
<iFrame class={iFrameClassName} src={url}></iFrame></template>
```

The child-component iFrame is shown when openIFrameHandler is fired but when a message is received from the IFrame and the iFrameClassName is set to 'hideIFrame' the classname in the child-component won't change.

As a matter of fact, the console logging in the eventListener is writing 'CLASSNAME: hideIFrame' but the tracked property is NOT changed, why is this?

I have also tried to set the eventhandler in the component constructor but it did not help.

How do I setup the event listener so that the iFrameClassName property is set when message is received?

I have previously worked with aura lightning components and this worked perfectly when set up in the parent components doInint method...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I finally managed to find a solution to this problem.
Because my eventlistener was declared using a normal function the context of 'this' was different to my class.

The solution was to use an arrow function like:
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {}.

This solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks had the same issue & this resolved for me.

Comment: What about removeEventListner in this case? Did you write it in the callback function and does it work?