# LWC: @track binding won't refresh component on value change

Tags: lightning-web-components, refresh, track

I have a component that picks up the value originally from the JS controller but won't refresh after I modify the value in the JS file.

Component:

```
<template>
    <div class={outterWrapperClass}/>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class SomeClass extends LightningElement {
    @track outterWrapperClass = 'outter-wrapper';

    connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            if (window.pageYOffset < 260) {
                this.outterWrapperClass = 'outter-wrapper';
            } else {
                this.outterWrapperClass = 'outter-wrapper-sidebar';
            }
            console.log('outer is ' + this.outterWrapperClass);
        });
    }
}
```

The value for `this.outterWrapperClass` is changing correctly in the console but the component's class value won't refresh. It's stuck on `outter-wrapper`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general sense, you'll want to have a separate function and bind that reference to the event handler:

```
connectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler.bind(this));
}
scrollHandler() {
    if (window.pageYOffset < 260) {
        this.outterWrapperClass = 'outter-wrapper';
    } else {
        this.outterWrapperClass = 'outter-wrapper-sidebar';
    }
    console.log('outer is ' + this.outterWrapperClass);
}
```

[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) will ensure that `this` refers to the component and not the window.

Comment: Thanks for providing some additional input.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266320/how-to-setup-eventlistener-for-a-lwc-component-to-receive-messages-from-an-embed).

In case that link disappears for whatever reason - The answer to this question is because I was using a regular function declaration so "this" was not what I was hoping to be. I had to switch to a fat arrow function and things worked out.